# Horizontal RecyclerView do not scroll to left after re-enabling scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The recyclerview with custom viewholders stop scrolling to left when scrolling is reenabled.

Based on the business logic I am disabling the scroll but as the user swipes to configurable distance I enabled the scroll (100px on x). Scrolling is fine if user does LTR but nothing happens if RTL is done.

The recyclerview has three views. V1, V2, and V3 but to make the recyclerview as carousel I am adding V3 at first index and V1 at last index, something like this `V3, V1, V2, V3, V1`. This way when the user reaches at the last visible view (V3), further swipe shows the first view (V1)

```
 list = listOf(scrollableData.last()) + scrollableData + listOf(
            scrollableData.first()
        )
```

Above logic works fine with V1, and V2 but not on V3 which I think causes the scrolling left disable. I might be wrong. I am doing anything else than what I have specified above.

**HomeActivity**

```
gestureDetector = GestureDetector(this@HomeActivity, object : CustomGestureDetector(recycler_view) {
            override fun move(): Boolean {
                enableScroll()
                return false
            }

            override fun down(): Boolean {
                disableScroll()
                return false
            }

        })
        recycler_view.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            if (event != null) {
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
            }
            false
        }

    override fun enableScroll() {
        linearLayoutManager.isScrollEnabled = true
    }

    override fun disableScroll() {
        linearLayoutManager.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
```

**CustomGestureDetector**

```
public abstract class CustomGestureDetector(view: View) : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    var view = view

    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        view.onTouchEvent(e)
        down()
        return false
    }

    override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent, e2: MotionEvent, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
        if (Math.abs(e2.x - e1.x) > 500) {
            move()
        }
        return false
    }

    abstract fun move(): Boolean
    abstract fun down(): Boolean
}
```

I hope I have provided enough information to understand the problem I am facing.

Comment: in your onFling function I think the if condition will work in one direction only, you have to add the second condition to it.

Comment: @UmarHussain no it works both ways, `Math.abs(..)` makes the resultant value positive. I already checked that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of implementing logic over the `recyclerview`. I created a custom `RelativeLayout` and implemented logic there, and used this layout for each item.

```
    class CustomRelativeLayot: RelativeLayout{
        ...
        override fun onTouchEvent(motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                when (motionEvent.action) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
pressedX = motionEvent.x
                disableScreenScroll()
                pressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
}
          }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    if (Math.abs(motionEvent.x - pressedX) > scrollSensitivity && isSwipable) {
    ...
                    }
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {}
    }
    return true
    }
```

**item.xml**

```
<com...CustomRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/airModuleLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/temp_height"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:isSwipable="true">
..
</com...CustomRelativeLayout>
```

I hope this helps someone else facing same issue.